# Silverlight Area Series chart: how to define interval for X-Axis

Tags: silverlight, charts

I have a silverlight chart with an Area Series.
my data source returns many points representing time of day to be displayed in the chart's X-axis.

since the X-axis has many values, the values appear scrambled as each value is stuck beside the next value.

is there a method to avoid displaying all the values in the X-axis and display intervals instead ?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DateTimeAxis` has `Interval` and `IntervalType` properties that allow you to set the interval the you prefer.

Comment: Thanks for response, but my axis has string values in the form of 10:30,10:31,etc.. not date time values, so can this be applied to my case ?

Comment: @Mina: in that case all the charting can see is a set of strings that have no meaning.  It has no way to know how to determine which can be dropped in order to increase clarity.  In fact it has no way to know that these are even linear.

Comment: @Mina:  You should create an explicit DateTimeAxis and either adjust the object so that it has a DateTime property or create a value converter to convert the strings into a DateTime.  Then specify an AxisLabelStyle to set the StringFormat to "{}{0:hh\\:mm}"

Comment: Thanks Anthony, I converted my data to date time and used the DateTimeAxis with intervals, I got the desired results.